# How to connect 20 shapes to a single 'OnMouseDown'?

Tags: delphi

I have a Delphi program which contains the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Shape1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  <code here>
end;
```

Thing is, I want the exact same code for all 20 shapes. How do I go around doing this effectively? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use multi-select (e.g. <kbd>SHIFT+CLICK</kbd>, or click and drag a selection rectangle) to select all 20 shapes.
2. In the Object Inspector set the `OnMouseDown` event handler to be the common event handler. This will assign the same event handler to all 20 selected shapes.
3. If you need to know which shape was clicked from inside your common event handler, use `(Sender as TShape)`.

Comment: I just tried that, I selected all 20 of them and then doubleclicked the OnMouseDown, but the resulting code is the exact same..

Comment: That's right. But now the single event handler is attached to all 20 buttons.

Comment: Ohhhh, I see! Thanks a lot that eases stuff up :D By the way, is there a way to do this process manually with code (setting a common Event Handler)?

Comment: In code you cannot assign an event handler, which is really just a property, to multiple objects in a single line of code. So you would need, say, a list of shapes and then a loop that iterated over the list to assign the event handler.

Comment: Ah, I see. One more thing. You edited your code and said to use (Sender as TShape). What do you mean by that? I come from basic C++ and I've never heard of a 'Sender'.

Comment: It's the first parameter to the `OnMouseDown` event. In this context it can be used to identify which shape the mouse was over when the mouse went down.